# spaCy 3.0.6 installation error on AWS notebook instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cython, spacy, spacy-3

I have been successfully installing spaCy 3.0.6 numerous times (without any issues) in the past. However, recently after restarting my AWS notebook instance, and trying to install spaCy 3.0.6, I received some installation errors. The code I am running is "!pip install spacy==3.0.6", and the error I receive is as follows:

```
Collecting spacy==3.0.6
  Using cached spacy-3.0.6.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [164 lines of output]
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          int length
      
      
      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/vocab.pxd:28:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      
      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/vocab.pxd:29:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      
      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/vocab.pxd:30:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
          cpdef public object _lookups
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/vocab.pxd:31:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
          cpdef public object _lookups
          cpdef public object writing_system
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/vocab.pxd:32:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
          cpdef public object _lookups
          cpdef public object writing_system
          cpdef public object get_noun_chunks
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/vocab.pxd:33:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef float prior_prob
      
      
      cdef class KnowledgeBase:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly Vocab vocab
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      spacy/kb.pxd:31:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      Copied /tmp/pip-install-tzzx03x0/spacy_7ff78434465a4b2c9a35b5b0714830d2/setup.cfg -> /tmp/pip-install-tzzx03x0/spacy_7ff78434465a4b2c9a35b5b0714830d2/spacy/tests/package
      Copied /tmp/pip-install-tzzx03x0/spacy_7ff78434465a4b2c9a35b5b0714830d2/pyproject.toml -> /tmp/pip-install-tzzx03x0/spacy_7ff78434465a4b2c9a35b5b0714830d2/spacy/tests/package
      Cythonizing sources
      Compiling spacy/training/example.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/parts_of_speech.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/strings.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/lexeme.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/vocab.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/attrs.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/kb.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/ml/parser_model.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/morphology.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/dep_parser.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/morphologizer.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/multitask.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/ner.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/pipe.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/trainable_pipe.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/sentencizer.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/senter.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/tagger.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/transition_parser.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/arc_eager.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/ner.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/nonproj.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/_state.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/stateclass.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/transition_system.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/_beam_utils.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokenizer.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/training/align.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/training/gold_io.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/doc.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/span.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/token.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/span_group.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/graph.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/morphanalysis.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/_retokenize.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/matcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/phrasematcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/dependencymatcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/symbols.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/vectors.pyx because it changed.
      [ 1/41] Cythonizing spacy/attrs.pyx
      [ 2/41] Cythonizing spacy/kb.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-vb09uo_8/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-vb09uo_8/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-vb09uo_8/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 224, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 211, in setup_package
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-vb09uo_8/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1134, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-vb09uo_8/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1301, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: spacy/kb.pyx
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am able to install the latest version of spaCy without any issues. However, I am in need of this specific version to be installed.

Comment: You need to force it to use an earlier version of Cython - probably the one that was current when it was first released